# Cocos2d v2.0 - Set Up Scenes, Layers, Sprites, etc

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scale, layer, scene

With Cocos2d v2.0.0, a lot of changes were made and a lot of people are experiencing some scaling problems and other conflicts ...

This is even more true if they read and test out Ray Wenderlich's great book : Learning Cocos2d : The viking guy is to big, the background is not centered, the suffix system for images is not working, ...

So, how to proceed ?

Comment: Could you add a link to where people are saying that they have these problems? Because if someone finds this question and has the same issues, they may want to read about the experiences other's are having as you said, and typically the solutions to these issues are found in the same posts. Also, it validates your point that "a lot of people" are experiencing issues. I haven't heard much of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, everything is already told in the sample project when creating a new cocos2d v2 project.
But, some of us need to get things pointed out.

- ### Image Suffix System for iPhone (Non-retina & Retina) and iPad (Non-retina & Retina)

Check out lines 68-71 from AppDelegate.m
Here is what you need to remember :

1. You just need to call

   ```
   CCSprite *mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySprite.png"];
   ```
2. No need for some if(iPad) then else if(iPhone) blabla
3. Make sure you called your images like as lines 68-71 from AppDelegate.m (Default : **mySprite.png** (iPhone) | **mySprite-hd.png** (iPhone Retina) | **mySprite-ipad.png** (iPad) | **mySprite-ipadhd.png** (iPad Retina)

- ### Calling a Scene

Check out line 76 from AppDelegate.m

1. Just call the scene function from your class (using pushScene)

   ```
   [director_ pushScene: [MyScene scene]];
   ```

- ### Adding layers to your scene class

1. Supposing your scene class is called with the +(CCSene*)scene function (which is a good practice for cocos2d v2)
2. ```
   +(CCScene *) scene
   {
       // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
       CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

       BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
       [scene addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];

       GameplayLayer *gameplayLayer = [GameplayLayer node];
       [scene addChild:gameplayLayer z:5];

       return scene;
   }
   ```

- ### Replacing the init function from your classes (CCScene, CCLayer, ...)

This is where scaling problems from v2 of cocos2d come from (but I do not know why).

1. Instead of calling -(id)init, call

   ```
   -(void) onEnter{ //Do some sprite displaying with [self addChild:mySprite]; }
   ```
2. You can still call the -(id)init function for other things you need to load before displaying sprites.

- ### Using SneakyInput (Joystick opensource library)

You can find how to use sneakyinput with cocos2d v2 here : http://cl.ly/1J2D2z0f3o0r3h041o3o

- ### Multi Touch Enabling

1. Add this line to your layer (in the +(CCScene*) scene function or else where)

   ```
   layer.isTouchEnabled = YES;
   ```
2. Then add this to the same .m

   ```
   - (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
   {
       NSArray *touchArray=[touches allObjects];

       if ([touchArray count] == 2)
       {
           NSLog(@"2");
       }
       else if([touchArray count]==1)
       {
           NSLog(@"1");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, go to the AppDelegate.m and add this :

   ```
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector].view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
   ```

*I would much appreciate if cocos2d v2 developers could help out and post stuff about how to use cocos2d v2 compared to v1.*

Comment: Honestly, apart from the initial rotation issue (winSize reports different dimensions in init vs onEnter for the first scene) cocos2d 2.0 behaves exactly like 1.0. Using pushScene seems to be optional, replaceScene can still be used. As for SneakyInput, only the Non-Skinned (CircleButton or something) classes can't be used, just leave them out of the project and use the "Skinned" classes.

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d v2.0 migration guide:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0